# C# always false bool

Tags: c#, boolean

Can anyone help? I can't work out why the bool floorOne is always set to false when I press button7, even if I press button3 or button1 first. This should be a fairly simple issue, it's only made false when initialised, when button2 is pressed or when button4 is pressed. I have no idea how it's returning to false.

It probably has a relatively simple solution, but I can't find it, thank you for your time.

Edit: When I debug, it shows up as false, I don't know if that information'll help at all. I know a lot of the code probably doesn't need to be included here, but just in case there was an issue in there somehow I thought I should add it in.

Edit2: Fantastic, thank you very much everyone!

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Elevator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool doorsOpen;
        public bool floorOne;
        public bool groundFloor;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox1.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = true; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
            pictureBox3.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox4.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors open picture
            floorOne = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = "Ground floor";
            button1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = false; // This makes it impossible to click the buttons if
            button5.Enabled = false; // the lift is already on that floor, to start with this is the
            button6.Enabled = true;  // ground floor.
            button5.BackColor = Color.Black;
            button6.BackColor = Color.Red;
            doorsOpen = true;
            richTextBox2.Text = "Doors open";
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorsOpen == true)
            {
                doorsOpen = false;
                richTextBox2.Text = "Doors closed";
            }
            pictureBox1.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
            pictureBox3.Visible = true; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox4.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors open picture
            bool floorOne = true;
            button1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            richTextBox1.Text = "First floor";
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = true;
            button6.Enabled = false;
            button5.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button6.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }

        public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorsOpen == true)
            {
                doorsOpen = false;
                richTextBox2.Text = "Doors closed";
            }
            pictureBox1.Visible = true; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
            pictureBox3.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox4.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors open picture
            bool floorOne = false;
            button1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            richTextBox1.Text = "Ground floor";
            button3.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            button5.Enabled = false; 
            button6.Enabled = true;  
            button5.BackColor = Color.Black;
            button6.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        public void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doorsOpen = true;
            richTextBox2.Text = "Doors open";
           if (floorOne == true)
           { 
            pictureBox1.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
            pictureBox3.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox4.Visible = true; // This is the top floor doors open picture
           }
           else if (floorOne != true)
           {
               pictureBox1.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
               pictureBox2.Visible = true; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
               pictureBox3.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
               pictureBox4.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors open picture
           }
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorsOpen == true)
            {
                doorsOpen = false;
                richTextBox2.Text = "Doors closed";
            }
            pictureBox1.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
            pictureBox3.Visible = true; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox4.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors open picture
            bool floorOne = true;
            button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            richTextBox1.Text = "First floor";
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = true;
            button6.Enabled = false;
            button5.BackColor = Color.Red;
            button6.BackColor = Color.Black;

        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorsOpen == true)
            {
                doorsOpen = false;
                richTextBox2.Text = "Doors closed";
            }
            pictureBox1.Visible = true; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
            pictureBox3.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
            pictureBox4.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors open picture
            bool floorOne = false;
            button1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            richTextBox1.Text = "Ground floor";
            button3.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            button5.Enabled = false;
            button6.Enabled = true;
            button5.BackColor = Color.Black;
            button6.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Side note `if (floorOne == true) ... else if (floorOne != true)` - are you sure you need to check if floor one is not true, if it's not true? Exactly same should be verified with `if (floorOne) .. else`

Comment: You should really name your variables and controls better.

Comment: you should use the debugger sometimes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in some of your methods you are declaring a *new* `floorOne` variable, instead of modifying the existing Form1's field.

Replace

```
bool floorOne = true;
```

with

```
floorOne = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Button3 and button4 click event remove the declaration of bool variable and just update the value of it. Because you already have defined the **bool floorOne** so you don't need to declare it again.

**Update**

```
bool floorOne = true;
```

**To**

```
floorOne = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

this realy have a simple solution.
Lets say, you click button1 and you want to set floorOne to true, but what you realy do is:
create new LOCAL boolean value floorOne and set it to true (bool floorOne = true;). But this doesnt change your GLOBAL value floorOne. It has the same name, but that doesnt matter in this case.
Delete the "bool" text in your code in button1 and then "floorOne" will be your global value.

new code for button1 (same change for all other buttons):

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (doorsOpen == true)
        {
            doorsOpen = false;
            richTextBox2.Text = "Doors closed";
        }
        pictureBox1.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors closed picture
        pictureBox2.Visible = false; // This is the bottom floor doors open picture
        pictureBox3.Visible = true; // This is the top floor doors closed picture
        pictureBox4.Visible = false; // This is the top floor doors open picture
        floorOne = true; // HERE IS THE CHANGE
        button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        button2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        richTextBox1.Text = "First floor";
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = true;
        button5.Enabled = true;
        button6.Enabled = false;
        button5.BackColor = Color.Red;
        button6.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool floorOne; // global value (automatically set to false (default value of false)

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool floorOne = true; // new local value named floorOne (doesn change your global value)
        MessageBox.Show("value of global floorOne is: " + this.floorOne.ToString());
        // this.floorOne is your global value (try to find something about "this.")
        this.floorOne = true;
        MessageBox.Show("value of global floorOne is: " + this.floorOne.ToString());
    }
}
```